# Recurrence tree diagram

Tags: recurrence-relations

I can generally do these but I feel like I'm missing a very basic piece of information. For example, the recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n$ is easy to draw out in a tree diagram, but for some reason I can't figure out a diagram for $2T(n/2) + 1$. What would the value of each node be at level $i$ in this case, it can't be the same as the first one right?